# Get the text inside the image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, resize, position

I have a question in regards HTML I want my text to be in the middle of the image not outside of the image. It has to be inside the image in a specific X and Y position.

My code so far:

```
  <center>
  <div style='position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: auto; overflow: show;'>
     <div id='loadingtext' style='margin-top: 10px; color: #666; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;'>Loading Text..</div>
     <img src='http://oi58.tinypic.com/2wmou89.jpg'>

    </div>
  </center>

  <div style='-webkit-box-reflect: below -120px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.1, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0))); position: absolute; top: 90%; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 5%; height: 100px; overflow: show; font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #888' id='files'>
  </div>

</div>
```

I would like the text to be in the middle of the image so that people can see the loading text in the middle of the image.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the minimal code required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Simple solution - use for text class `z-index`. And positioning text where you want inside image.

Comment: Sorry for posting a whole chunk the issue is in here!

Comment: The image should have "position: relative" and the text should be "position: absolute".

Comment: So I tried doing that but it still doesn't work here is the result: I marked it how i want it: http://i59.tinypic.com/2vk0tx4.png I tried to change the paths did not work.

Comment: Here is the changed code the image is still thesame. http://pastebin.com/Zgs4KKMH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: Please remove the keyword "javascript" and replace it by "css" ;)

2nd: The following is a most easy CSS solution. You would need another solution or javascript if the text cannot have a fixed width. But I would suggest to use a fixed width anyway because long lines are ugly.
Forget about the terrible z-index solutions. We do not need z-index. The order of the elements has the same purpose.

3rd: **solution**

```
<div style="position: absolute;">
    <img src="http://oi58.tinypic.com/2wmou89.jpg">
    <div id="loadingtext" style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; color: #666; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; margin-top:-6px; width:128px; margin-left:-64px; font-weight: bold;">Loading Text..</div>
</div>
```

margin-top is 0-(font-size/2) and margin-left is 0-(width/2) ...

Comment: Welcome. BTW: If you want to use it in a "page flow" you must put it in another <div style="position: relative;">[CODE FROM ABOVE]</div>

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the containing div's position from absolute to relative and set the div with the id=loadingtext to absolute , z-index and position it according to your needs (eg: left:50%; top:50%;) and the text will be on top of the image.